# colspan doesn't accept decimal numbers. How do I specify the span?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th colspan="4">Liquor Store Blues</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Meow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Meow</td>
            <td colspan="2">Meow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1.33">Meow</td>
            <td colspan="1.33">Meow</td>
            <td colspan="1.33">Meow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Meow</td>
            <td>Meow</td>
            <td>Meow</td>
            <td>Meow</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have got an image of it over here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzCaz.png

Wanted to set each `td`'s `colspan` in the 4th row to `1.44` but then I came to know that `colspan` doesn't take decimal numbers. So how do I do it? Should I have to use CSS? If so, how?

Comment: Multiply all your spans so that they end up as integers. http://html-tables.com/ might be helpful.

Comment: I have a hard time believing this is tabular data.

Comment: Colspan take integer values.  Colspan is different from width.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarcAudet Am trying to make the 4th row occupy all the space inside the table just like the other rows.

Comment: That's... not how a table works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of your 4th row having 3 elements, your table actually has 12 columns, not 4.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/9lzcwolh

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th colspan="12">Liquor Store Blues</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td colspan="12">A1</td> </tr>
      
        <tr><td colspan="6">B1</td><td colspan="6">B2</td></tr>
      
        <tr><td colspan="4">C1</td><td colspan="4">C2</td><td colspan="4">C3</td></tr>
      
        <tr><td colspan="3">D1</td> <td colspan="3">D2</td> <td colspan="3">D3</td><td colspan="3">D4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: 4 * 3 = 12.  Drawing in the last row might help visualize it better:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/xfwrekym

Comment: I can't figure out how there are 12 columns... could you please explain me... I really don't get it. :(

Comment: This goes back to learning fractions.  You have to find the least common denominator between 1/3 (4th row) and 1/4 (5th row) in order to be able to compare them.  That's where the 12 comes from, it is the lowest common denominator for 3 and 4.  The elements of the 4th row are 4/12ths of the width of the table, while the elements in the 5th row are 3/12ths.

Answer (score 2):

For that row you can use the following HTML using a nested table:

```
<tr><td colspan="4">
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td>Meow</td>
     <td>Meow</td>
     <td>Meow</td>
   </tr></table>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: why would someone down vote the obvious answer to the question? This is much more user friendly then adding extra columns to make what you are trying to do divisible into integers.

Comment: Assuming the table is used to display tabular data in the first place (which I doubt, but let's pretend), the nested table is clearly being used for layout.  That's why it's bad design.  There's no need to *make extra columns* to do it the right way unless your browser is quite old.

Comment: yah but if they decide to add a fifth row that has five columns, you have to go back and rework all of your numbers to have the layout stay the same and that to me seems like bad design. That being said your way of handling the issue is a very interesting way of dealing with the problem, i'm just looking more bigger picture.