# JSF table with varying number of columns across rows

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Does vanilla JSF 2.0 support datatable with varying number of columns across different rows?

I have a 2 dimensional array in my Java bean, in some rows only one column contains data. For those rows I want them appear as merged. ie without borders between columns, and data able to use the width of the adjacent columns for display.

Is this reasonable to do without additional JSF frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with vanilla HTML table instead of the JSF one. Just **implement a double iteration for your matrix**. Supposing you're able to use EL 2.2 expressions in your environment:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ArrayBean {

    private Integer[][] array = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1 } };

    public Integer[][] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

}
```

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <table border="1">
        <ui:repeat var="row" value="#{arrayBean.array}">
            <tr>
                <ui:repeat var="column" value="#{row}">
                    <td colspan="#{fn:length(arrayBean.array) / fn:length(row)}"
                        align="center">#{column}</td>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This solution doesn't take into account you could have [decimal colspans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795358/colspan-doesnt-accept-decimal-numbers-how-do-i-specify-the-span), so you should calculate the lowest common denominator for your column number. That's, however, out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. My two main concerns are now resolved. 1. Getting row index, which can be done with varStatus.index. 2. Set colspan to values other than 1 or row.length, which can be done by substituting in whatever other EL expression that works.